# IIS Express denying PUT requests in ADO.Net data services

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, wcf-data-services

I have a project that uses ado.net dataservices.  This project was originally developed in VS2005 and IIS6 but I am now porting it to IIS7 standards.  I've run into a snag when trying to update existing records, the put operation (to the service) fails and prompts the following browser alert:

> The URI 'http://localhost:6188/services/Datatracker.svc/provider' is not valid for PUT operation. The URI must point to a single resource for PUT opeations.

I imagine this is because the URI is being treated as a folder, and I know that this can be corrected through configuration but I'm having trouble finding the specific settings

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: WHat is the response when you do a GET to that URL. If your service follows the standard addressing scheme used by WCF Data Services then it should be an entity set (the response should be a feed) in which case PUT is indeed invalid (what does it mean to update an entity set?) you can only issue POST to entity set URIs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I ended up figuring this one out on my own though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out this is invalid syntax for put and delete requests:

```
http://localhost:6188/services/Datatracker.svc/provider
```

Valid odata syntax is: (OLKM represents the calue of the keyfield that uniquely identifies the record)

```
http://localhost:6188/services/Datatracker.svc/provider('OLKM')
```

Old asp.net + iis6 allowed you to cheat your way around this requirement, but iis7 & .net 3.5+ requires you to use the correct syntax.